# Asymptotic inequalities, if $a(n)\sim b(n)$ and $b(n)<c(n)$, what can be said about $a(n)$ and $c(n)$?

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics

If $a(n) \sim  b(n)$, that is, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} a(n)/b(n)=1 $. And $b(n)<c(n)$, what relation can established between $a(n)$ and $c(n)?$

For example, if $b(n)<c(n)$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$, is true that $a(n)<c(n)?$

Comment: No, consider $a=n+2$, $b=n$, and $c=n+1$

Comment: You at least get $a(n) = O(c(n))$, assuming $a(n), b(n) > 0$.